# python grammar specification : typedargslist

Tags: python-3.x, bnf, default-parameters

I was checking [python grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html),and functions in python are defined like this using BNF.

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite

parameters: '(' [typedargslist] ')'
typedargslist: (tfpdef ['=' test] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])* [',' [
        '*' [tfpdef] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' tfpdef [',']]]
      | '**' tfpdef [',']]]
  | '*' [tfpdef] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' tfpdef [',']]]
  | '**' tfpdef [','])
tfpdef: NAME [':' test]
```

Here is the problem:I thought python does not allow non-default arguments before default arguments but clearly the BNF definition states otherwise.And I checked it in python 3.5 which  raised an error like this.

```
    def my(c=1,a:1*2,*,b):
          ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Can any one tell me which one is right?

Answer (score 1):

Python does indeed disallow this. See [8.6 Function Definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> If a parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the “*” must also have a default value — **this is a syntactic restriction that is not expressed by the grammar**.

(Emphasis mine)